# CSS button text disappear when accessing target page, only appears when hovering

Tags: css, wordpress, button

I am trying to design a button for a multi-lingual Wordpress site, in order to access the contact page. The problem appears when I click on it and access the target contact page. At this point the text in the button disappears, and only reappears when I hover over the button. The text appears normally in all the other pages, this only occurs when I access the target page. I will attach some screenshots below of the button working normally in other pages, how it looks when hovering over it and how it looks when accessing the contact page where the problem appears.

[image: Button working in other pages]

[image: Button as it appears when hovering over it in all pages(including contact page)]

[image: Button text dissapears when accessing the contact page]

I have tried different codes for creating the button but the problems keeps appearing. Below is the code I am currently using.

```css
.btn-class-eng{
border-radius: 50px;
padding: 0px 40px;
color: #ffffff;
border-color: #4064d7;
background-color: #4064d7;
}
.btn-class-eng a {
color:#fff;
}
.btn-class-eng:hover{
opacity:0.8;
color:#4064D7; 
background-color:#3A3A3A;
}
```

I expect the text to appear on the button when not hovering over it, as it does in all the other pages.

Comment: Your HTML please

Comment: You should start by inspecting the element in your browser, and check what styles actually get applied in this situation, and where they originate from.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS block, too:

```
.btn-class-eng a:visited, .btn-class-eng a:link {
    color:#fff;
}
```

All visited links turn blue, by default, making the background and the text, both, blue. Hence, it looks as if the text disappeared.

`a: visited` makes sure that if the link is already visited, it still remains white in colour.

Corrected: as suggested by @04fs.

Comment: That should probably be `.btn-class-eng a:visited, .btn-class-eng a:link`, otherwise you are formatting _all_ elements matching `a:link` in the whole document.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the correction @04FS. I have edited the answer to reflect your correction.